# Limiting message prefetching with Arduino MQTT library

Tags: arduino, rabbitmq, mqtt

I'm using knolleary's Arduino library for MQTT connected to RabbitMQ with the MQTT plugin. Whilst the RabbitMQ configuration example states that I can set prefetch, it doesn't seem to have any effect.

My messages are large and take time to process on the Arduino and it seems they're pulled instantly by the Arduino until the ethernet buffer is full and it falls over - I can't see any going into 'ready' in the RabbitMQ management console.

Is this because the Arduino library does not support Qos1, so the prefetch is ignored without acknowledgement? I'm assuming so as in AMQP prefetch requires ack as well. Any way round this without adding Qos-1 to the library (which is a bit beyond me and it seems the library has not been updated for quite a while so Qos1 seems not likely to appear).

Comment: You say your messages are large; could they be bigger than the arfuino client limit?

Comment: knolleary will be able answer definitively but I am 95% sure the Arduino client is QOS 0 only because it has no local storage support

Comment: Can you define 'large'. By default the library has a limit of 128 bytes for messages - unless you change the constant in PubSubClient.h.

Comment: I've updated your library so I can send through ~50k image files. (there's a small bug in doing this which I'll get contributed back today). It might help to have explained the use case a bit more - the queue is sending black and white bitmaps for printing on a thermal printer. The files are saved off to SD (soon to be external SRAM) before being read back and sent to the printer. The printing is quite slow which is why if there's a lot of messages (they're a tweetstream) then it starts to backup until the ethernet's (wizio820) buffer fills.

Comment: First up, I don't know anything about RabbitMQ and 'prefetch' and how that interacts with MQTT QoS levels. The arduino client only supports, and only subscribes at QoS 0. Being single threaded, when the message arrived callback occurs, it is up to you to save away the payload before you return from the callback as the internal buffer of the client will then get reused.

Comment: Oh, and as @hardillb says, the lack of qos1/2 support in the client is on purpose as we don't have the storage to provide proper assured delivery.

Comment: Yeah I thought that would be the case. I think I'm going to have to take a different approach as without ack I can't get the queue to backlog the messages - it will just keep sending them. Okay plan B...

Comment: I think I'll have a go at adding in QOS1 for SUBSCRIBE so that receiving messages for the Arduino can be acknowledged. Sending can still be QOS0 only as that would require local storage until the server ack'd. It seems the protocol allows this and would mean all I have to add is the ability to set QOS in the subscribe function and and ack function which sends a PUBACK when the server publishes to the client and the processing is complete. Will let you know how I get on.